# How can I combine two jQuery selects that use .on?

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery:

```
$('#detail')
.on('click', '.deleteLink', function () {
    dialog(this);
    return false;
})
$('#detail')
.on('click', '.editLink', function () {
    dialog(this);
    return false;
})
```

Is there a way these could be combined. Sorry but I don't know jQuery at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match both selectors with `,`, like in CSS:

```
$('#detail').on('click', '.deleteLink, .editLink', function () {
    dialog(this);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Either bind it to a parent of both using the comma selector:

```
// Instead of body, you might want a more specific common parent
$('body').on('click', '#detailD .deleteLink, #detail .editLink', function () {
    dialog(this);
    return false;
});
```

Or you can simply create the function once:

```
var handler = function () {
    dialog(this);
    return false;
};
$('#detailD').on('click', '.deleteLink', handler);
$('#detail').on('click', '.editLink', handler);
```

Comment: And, for everyone who thinks they know jQuery, the second way is how almost all your code should look like – anonymous functions are pretty, but they are used in the docs because they are easy to use for small examples, not because all code should look like that! :)

Comment: I am sorry I just made a correction. It's just the one element. detail and not detailD.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work assuming .deleteLink is a child element of your selectors

```
$('#detailD > .deleteLink, #detail > .deleteLink')
    .on('click', function () {
        dialog(this);
        return false;
    });​
```